# Evaluation order of Gradle multi-project build

Tags: gradle, semantics

I am using Gradle 6.5.1. According to [the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/build_lifecycle.html), the build proceeds in 3 phases: initialisation, configuration, and execution.

However, in reality, things seem to be a bit more complicated than that. I have a minimal, complete verified example (MCVE) at https://github.com/greenrd/evaluation-order.

It seems to me as though there are multiple sub-phases involved in the configuration phase.

The issue is reproduced by typing

```
gradle clean :client:test --stacktrace
```

which produces a lot of output; however, the key lines are these:

```
Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.typelevel:cats-core_2.12:2.2.0.
Required by:
    project :client > org.http4s:http4s-circe_2.12:0.21.8 > org.http4s:http4s-core_2.12:0.21.8
    project :client > org.http4s:http4s-circe_2.12:0.21.8 > org.http4s:http4s-core_2.12:0.21.8 > org.typelevel:cats-effect_2.12:2.2.0
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configuring the dependency resolve details with 'null' version is not allowed.
```

I thought to myself, "OK, the reason it is null is because the scalaExt [script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins) has not been evaluated yet at that point in time", so I uncommented this code on line 1 of `gradle/magnolia.gradle`:

```
//apply from: scalaExt
```

But it seems my assumption was incorrect because it then gives a *different* error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$DuplicateTaskException: Cannot add task 'printAll' as a task with that name already exists.
```

And crucially, note that in the stack trace above the "Caused by", *the uncommented line appears*:

```
       at magnolia_ae70fbynee6mpgv2bzwlr0v6i.run(/home/user/mcve/evaluation-order/gradle/magnolia.gradle:1)
```

That's the really weird thing about this. If it were simply a problem of me misunderstanding the semantics of the Gradle DSL and getting the evaluation order mixed up, then it should be the case that uncommenting this line fixes the order of evaluation, by making sure that the script plugin gets applied early enough. So this "DuplicateTaskException" error should not have occurred the very *first* time such an `apply from` was executed, but if it occurred at all, at the *second* time. Because if it occurs the first time, how can the task already exist?!

So in the original project before that line was uncommented, we seem to be in this weird halfway state where the plugin script has been evaluated... yet some of the variables it declares are still null?! Why is that? I'm really confused, and I can't find or come up with any explanation of why the Gradle DSL should behave in this strange, contradictory way. One minute the evaluation order is one way, and then when you uncomment a single line, the evaluation order is something else?

What is the true evaluation order of multi-project Gradle builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a typo. `cats_v` should have been `cats_core_v`.